# How to get Grid view count column information upon clicking grid item in flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-gridview

Hi developers i have been using gridview in my flutter app to display some data's my gridview which has `crossAxisCount: 5` which is 5 columns so when clicking an item from gridview i want more information like which column user have clicked like below

[image]

so when user clicks **info3** and **info8** from the gridview is it possible or a way we can get **col3** is clicked? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Simple logic can do your job. Just do modulo of index with crossAxisCount. Something like this.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int crossAxisCount = 4;
    return GridView.builder(
        itemCount: 40,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount),
        itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
          return InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              print("Col${(index % crossAxisCount) + 1}");
            },
            child: Text("Item $index"),
          );
        });
  }
```

Comment: thanks this was what i was looking for i have accepted your answer